# How to change Nameservers using Ionos.com

Tags: dns, nameservers

I've been trying to change my nameservers using Ionos.com because I recently bought my own domain. I've been trying to link the domain to a 3rd party hosting site [x10hosting.com](https://x10hosting.com/)

I've had no luck finding any way to change it, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register a new domain, it is pointed to a default nameservers by the domain registrar.

You can edit the domain nameservers to point to your hosting provider.

To edit IONOS nameservers, follow the below steps.

The domain NS management is located within the Domain Management Dashboard.

Here is how to locate it when you are logged into your IONOS account.

1. Click on the Manage Domain link for the domain listed that you wish to set the nameservers. This leads you to the domains overview page
2. Click the Name Server tab along the top. You’ll then be presented with the list of name server entries actively in use.
3. Click the Use Custom Nameservers button. This will lead to a page with four text boxes for name server entry.
4. Enter the nameservers you want to use in the first and second boxes. The third and fourth boxes are optional and do not need any data entered. Click Save when finished.

Upon successful change, you’ll see a green notification stating that it was successful. It also advises about the standard DNS Propagation time.

If you receive any error messages while attempting to modify your nameservers, make sure there is no extra white-space (such as a space character, or a tab character) that made it into the box with your nameserver entry. This will cause an error with most registrars.

Keep in mind, DNS nameserver changes like this can take up to 24 – 48 hours to globally propagate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203067/discussion-on-answer-by-oladosu-abass-how-to-change-nameservers-using-ionos-com).

Comment: "When you register a new domain, it is pointed to a default nameservers by the domain registrar." This is false. Any registrar is mandated, at least by ICANN in gTLDs to let the registrant choose whatever nameserver it wishes. Registrars are also not necessarily DNS provider as this is a completely different job.

Comment: Hey Patrick, Stop misleading people with your false information. I am not sure what you are trying to derive from it. And the examples you gave previously before the comments were moved to chat was very wrong......Most domain registrars are also host provider which is the major reason why they have default nameservers. So when a domain is registered, it is automatically pointed ti their default NS. If you would want to point the domain to a different nameserver, you will have to manage your domain and edit the nameservers. This is only possible after the domain has been registered not during.